# Spring-Data-Cassandra map with UDT as value not mapped to java map.

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Cassandra Table Column:

```
pickuploc map<text, frozen<location>>
```

Java entity:

```
@Column("pickuploc")
protected Map<String,Location> pickupLocation;
```

When execute select query from the table column "pickuploc" not exactly getting mapped to pickupLocation attribute in defined in the entity.

Here is the response I got:

```
"pickupLocation": {
            "4171": {
                "type": {
                    "name": "UDT",
                    "keyspace": "delivery",
                    "typeName": "location",
                    "frozen": true,
                    "fieldNames": [
                        "buid"],
                    "typeArguments": [],
                    "collection": false
                }
            }
        }
```

Using Spring-Data-Casandra-1.5.8

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Cassandra supports as of 1.5 and 2.0 only primitive types within maps. There's already a [ticket to improve `Map` support](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-409). Leave your vote to increase the demand to get it implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed in version 2.2.
See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-487